# position:fixed in Android HTC Incredible 2?

Tags: android, css, mobile

`position:fixed` works in iPhone / iOS, but my sticky footer just begins to hang out in the middle of the page not staying fixed for android / htc?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

enter this code in your html.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: That may have allowed :fixed to work, but also made the site render grossly zoomed in. Hm..

Comment: I would add a big warning to this based of my own experience. On many devices select boxes are not usable when using user-scalable=no